# C# OleDb SQL Update syntax error

Tags: c#, ms-access

I cannot figure out why this gives me a syntax error when trying to update this?

```
string editComp = "UPDATE Competitive SET (PartNumber, Location, Description) values (@Edpart, @Edlocation, @Eddescrip) where SerialNumber = @serial";
command.CommandText = editComp;
command.Parameters.Add("@serial", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Serialtext.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Edpart", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Parttext.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Edlocation", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cboLocation.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Eddescrip", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Descriptiontext.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated");
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute an update query with syntax of an insert. use correct syntax for [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) like the following;

```
 string editComp = "UPDATE Competitive SET PartNumber=@Edpart, Location=@Edlocation, Description=@Eddescrip";
```

If the above code is not working then try replacing `@Edlocation`,`@Eddescrip` and `@Edpart` with `?`

Comment: Well I changed to the above and added this to the end  -  WHERE SerialNumber=@serial. It says it has updated but it doesn't actually update.

Comment: The add, delete statements I put in work just fine with "@" .

Comment: enclose the statements within a try and check whether any exception is comming

Comment: I already have it enclosed , that's why I was getting the syntax error from before. Now it shows my message box but no actual update.

Comment: Got it!,,,,By adding the serial number parameter first but not using it until the end of the statement it would not work. Moved the serial number to the end of the parameters I added and now it works, thank you for getting me started.